How do I print a python slice as a string separated by ":"?
I have a slice object, and I'd like to print it out in the form of a string start:stop:step. How do I do so?

From your link "Slice objects have read-only data attributes start, stop, and step which merely return the argument values (or their default)."

s = slice(1, 2, 3); print(f"{s.start}:{s.stop}:{s.step}") ?

There's nothing built-in that does this AFAIK. You'll need to write your own formatting code using the start, stop, and step attributes of the object.

@AndrejKesely That won't work well if any of the attributes are None, which is used for default values.

@AndrejKesely If the step is the default, you usually just want start:stop, not start:stop:

There's nothing built-in to do this, as far as I know, but we can easily write some code to do it using the values from the slice object, per the docs:

Slice objects have read-only data attributes start, stop, and step which merely return the argument values (or their default).

At the most basic
def slice_to_str(s: slice) -> str:
    return f'{s.start!r}:{s.stop!r}:{s.step!r}'

For example:
>>> print(slice_to_str(slice(15, 95, 5)))
15:95:5
>>> print(slice_to_str(slice(60)))
None:60:None

If you want to remove Nones
You can use ... is not None else ''
def slice_to_str(s: slice) -> str:
    start, stop, step = [
        (repr(val) if val is not None else '')
        for val in [s.start, s.stop, s.step]]
    return f'{start}:{stop}:{step}'

For example:
>>> print(slice_to_str(slice(60)))
:60:
>>> print(slice_to_str(slice(None)))
::
>>> print(slice_to_str(slice(None, None, 2)))
::2
>>> print(slice_to_str(slice('h', 't')))
'h':'t':

If you want to remove the last colon when the step is None
Just add a check for it: if s.step is None ...
def slice_to_str(s: slice) -> str:
    start, stop, step = [
        (repr(val) if val is not None else '')
        for val in [s.start, s.stop, s.step]]
    step_optional = f':{step}' if s.step is not None else ''
    return f'{start}:{stop}{step_optional}'

For example:
>>> print(slice_to_str(slice(60)))
:60
>>> print(slice_to_str(slice(None)))
:
>>> print(slice_to_str(slice(None, None, 2)))
::2


Don’t overthink it:
my_slice = slice(1,False,3)
print(f'{my_slice.start if my_slice.start is not None else ""}:{my_slice.stop if my_slice.stop is not None else ""}{(":"+str(my_slice.step)) if my_slice.step is not None else ""}')

Repl.it

What about slice(1, 10)? This should ideally produce 1:10, not 1:10:

@Barmar Are 1:10 and 1:10: not functionally equivalent? It wouldn’t be shocking to me if the answer was "no" but I’ve never run into such in my experience

@esqew That's why I said "ideally". I think they're equivalent, but the extra : is not pythonic.

@Barmar Of course, makes sense to me. Updated snippet should address this. Thanks as always!

@esqew 1:10 and 1:10: are equivalent. They both result in slice(1, 10, None).

I just realized strings are also valid values, e.g. my_slice = slice('') should be :'', not :. I updated my answer. For yours, you could do repr(my_slice.<start/stop>) if ... and ":"+repr(my_slice.step). To be clear, strings aren't used in the stdlib AFAIK, but they are used in Pandas at least.

Or, even in the stdlib, you'd want to distinguish between a mistake like slice('9') and slice(9).
